# Cant get the mysql bit(m) type working correctly, i think

Tags: mysql, bit-fields

I've been trying to get the bit type working in my database but cant figure how to use it.

example:

```
create table test(test_flags bit(8));

INSERT INTO test (test_flags) VALUES (b'11111111');
```

The resulting data is:

```
"00110010"
```

Why does this happen? all bit fields starts with "00110" no matter what I insert..

Comment: My first guess was that "00110010" was the ASCII value of the first character (1) in the string "11111111". But it turns out that would be "00110001". However, I would guess it is something like that. Try turning on strict mode and see if you get an error message about truncated data.

Comment: `SELECT BIN( test_flags ) FROM  test` returns 11111111 for me. How you are selecting the data?

Comment: I view the data in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Thanks Darhazer, i guess i cant just simply look at the data in phpmyadmin.. i have to use bin()...